# Different output on leetcode compared to terminal

Tags: python, reverse

I am trying to solve the following leetcode problem: [https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-vowels-of-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com).

I made the following code:

def reverseVowels(s):

```
i = 0
index_vowels = {}

for character in s:
    if character in ['a', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'i', 'A', 'E', 'O', 'U', 'I']:
        index_vowels[i] = character
    i += 1

keys = list(index_vowels.keys())
values = list(index_vowels.values())

reversed_keys = list(reversed(keys))

new_dict = zip(reversed_keys, values)

for key, value in new_dict:
    s = s[:key] + value + s[key + 1:]
return s
```

print(reverseVowels(s = "race a car"))

This works well on my computer and prints the expected output of "raca e car". On leetcode, however, it says that the output is "reca a car". How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python only maintain the order of insertions starting form python 3.6. I assume leetcode has an older version, so there iterating a dictionary gives you an arbitrary order. Since you're not using the dictionary lookup anyway, and are only interested in maintaining two sequences of keys and values, you could remove the dictionary altogether:

```py
def reverseVowels(s):
    keys = []
    values = []
    
    for i, character in enumerate(s):
        if character in ['a', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'i', 'A', 'E', 'O', 'U', 'I']:
            keys.append(i)
            values.append(character)

    reversed_keys = list(reversed(keys))

    new_dict = zip(reversed_keys, values)

    for key, value in new_dict:
        s = s[:key] + value + s[key + 1:]
    return s

print(reverseVowels(s = "race a car"))
```